# .replace() all instances with Regex not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have been looking on a million forms and have tried them all. I need to replace all instances of the text with the value

```
this.text = {
    title:'This is my Title',
};

this.replaceTags = function() {
    //Replace Text
    $.each(this.text, function( index, value ){
        var item = "{{$text:"+index+"}}";
        var bodyText = $('body').html();
        var regex = new RegExp(item, 'g');
        var newText = bodyText.replace(regex,value);
        $('body').html(newText);
    })
}
```

I have also tried

```
this.text = {
    title:'This is my Title',
};

this.replaceTags = function() {
    //Replace Text
    $.each(this.text, function( index, value ){
        var item = "{{$text:"+index+"}}";
        var bodyText = $('body').html();
        var newText = bodyText.replace(/item/g,value);
        $('body').html(newText);
    })
}
```

But neither are working. Do I have the syntax wrong?

Comment: Please provide a **complete** example and tell which steps you have taken to [debug](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [the problem](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging).

Answer (score 2):

Since `$` is a special character in a regular expression (it matches the end of the line), you have to escape it with `\`. Since `\` is a special character in strings (it's the escape character) you have to escape itself. Thus your code becomes:

```
var item = "{{\\$text:"+index+"}}";
var bodyText = $('body').html();
var regex = new RegExp(item, 'g');
var newText = bodyText.replace(regex,value);
$('body').html(newText);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tmLdK/)

---

`bodyText.replace(/item/g,value)` would literally look for the character sequence `item`, so that wouldn't work either way.